# adding month multiple times does not work

Tags: php, date

why this code does not work as planed?

Code:

```
$regDate = '2016-10-03';
    echo $date1 = date('m', strtotime('+4 month', strtotime($regDate))); echo '<br>';
    echo $date2 = date('m', strtotime('+4 month', strtotime($date1))); echo '<br>';
    echo $date3 = date('m', strtotime('+4 month', strtotime($date2))); echo '<br>';
    echo $date4 = date('m', strtotime('+4 month', strtotime($date3))); echo '<br>';
```

i get back :

02
05
05
05

Comment: Have you tried with using `YYYY-MM-DD` format dates?

Comment: i need it to give only month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not able to identify the dates. You need to calculate the dates first then `echo` them. Try with -

```
$regDate = '2016-10-03';
$date1 = strtotime('+4 month', strtotime($regDate)); 
echo date('m', $date1) . '<br>';
$date2 = strtotime('+4 month', $date1); 
echo date('m', $date2) . '<br>';
$date3 = strtotime('+4 month',$date2);
echo date('m', $date3) . '<br>';
$date4 = strtotime('+4 month', $date3);
echo date('m', $date4) . '<br>';
```

Another simple way would be -

```
$regDate = strtotime('2016-10-03');
foreach(range(1, 4) as $val) {
   $regDate = strtotime('+4 month', $regDate);
   echo date('m', $regDate) . '<br>';
}
```

**Output**

```
02
06
10
02
```

Comment: Check the method with loop. That is much easier and simpler.

Comment: Thanks!I appreciate it :)

Comment: How to use this FOR EACH result in if statement ?

Comment: *FOR EACH result*?

Comment: date('m', $regDate) i want it to be if(date('m', $regDate)==datenow){echo something} if i add my table inside loop it gets big with unneeded TD

Comment: Store it in a variable.

Comment: if that variable is outside loop it returns only 1 last data

Comment: You can use array also.